# ImageMagick's "-transparent white" working for PNG output but not SVG

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So in cmd prompt, I just put

```
convert test.png -transparent white transparent.png
```

If I replace the .png with .svg , the new file is made. However, it isn't transparent. 
What can I do?

Reason I prefer using svg file over png: It is a vector image.

Comment: Googling `imagemagick svg to png transparent` seems to yield loads of good results. Always check Google out first

Comment: Oh I tried that but I dont want to convert it into png I want it to remain svg

Comment: Are you sure your white is really white (as in 255/255/255 R/G/B)?

Comment: But what does that have to do with svg? If I use png, everything is fine. But if I use svg, the conversion doesnt happen. It is the same image :)

Comment: on.svg and on.png. I want to use on.svg not on.png but conversion only happens with on.png

Comment: Yeah, I see. Don't know why it doesn't work - although it's likely because it's a vector format. For a bitmap format, it just needs to replace every white pixel with a transparent one. For a vector format, it isn't that easy. Not sure whether this can be done.

Comment: Oh alright! I would be happy to see if anyone came up with a solution

Comment: I agree that I can use imagemagick for the image size I might need but things are much more cleaner in svg

Comment: You didn't show how your input file looks, nor say what you expected the command to do, so it is rather hard to help you. As it stands, your command replaces everything that is white with transparent areas. If your `svg` is blue, this isn't going to help much. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Both the inputs are identical in nature , one is .png and one is .svg (both have white background). I expect the command to replace all the white areas in .svg file to transparent! The reason it doesnt work is imagemagick is bit mapped oriented so how do I make it changes to vector images.

Comment: Try using `convert -background none image.svg ......` or sharing your SVG with us so we can experiment.

Comment: You SVG's "white" is most likely inherited from the document style (unset by default). Like @MarkSetchell pointed out, you need to define what the background is before reading the vectors. `convert -background transparent image.svg -transparent white`